# complateTransition don't dismiss the from view swift 2

Tags: ios, animation, transition, swift2

I am trying to set an interactive transition with this class :

```
class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerContextTransitioning {

weak var transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?

var sourceViewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet {
        enterPanGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer()
        enterPanGesture.addTarget(self, action:"panned:")
        enterPanGesture.edges = UIRectEdge.Left
        sourceViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(enterPanGesture)
    }
}
var togoSourceViewController: UIViewController!

let duration    = 1.0
var presenting  = true
var reverse = false
var originFrame = CGRectNull
var shouldBeInteractive = false

private var didStartedTransition = false
private var animated = false
private var interactive = false
private var AnimationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle(rawValue: 1)
private var didFinishedTransition = false
private var percentTransition: CGFloat = 0.0
private var enterPanGesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer!
private var tovc = UIViewController()
private var pointtovc = CGPoint()
private var pointfromvc = CGPoint()
private var fromvc = UIViewController()
private var generalcontainer = UIView()

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    animated = true

    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!

    if reverse {
        toViewController.view.center.x -= (container?.bounds.size.width)!
        container?.insertSubview(toViewController.view, aboveSubview: fromViewController.view)
    } else {
        toViewController.view.center.x += (container?.bounds.size.width)!
        container?.addSubview(toViewController.view)
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations: {
        if self.reverse {
            toViewController.view.center.x += (container?.bounds.size.width)!
        } else {
            toViewController.view.center.x -= (container?.bounds.size.width)!
        }
        }, completion: { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            self.animated = false
            self.reverse = !self.reverse
    })
}

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return duration
}

func startInteractiveTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    interactive = true
    animated = true

    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)! //ArticleView
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)! //Article OU Favoris

    if reverse {
        toViewController.view.frame.origin.x = -fromViewController.view.frame.maxX
        container?.insertSubview(toViewController.view, aboveSubview: fromViewController.view)
    }
    tovc = toViewController
    pointtovc = toViewController.view.bounds.origin
    fromvc = fromViewController
    pointfromvc = fromViewController.view.bounds.origin
    generalcontainer = container!
}

func containerView() -> UIView? {
    return sourceViewController?.view
}

func viewControllerForKey(key: String) -> UIViewController? {
    return sourceViewController?.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(key)
}

func viewForKey(key: String) -> UIView? {
    return sourceViewController?.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(key).view
}

func initialFrameForViewController(vc: UIViewController) -> CGRect {
    return vc.view.frame
}

func finalFrameForViewController(vc: UIViewController) -> CGRect {
    return vc.view.frame
}

func isAnimated() -> Bool {
    return animated
}

func isInteractive() -> Bool {
    return interactive
}

func presentationStyle() -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return AnimationStyle!
}

func completeTransition(didComplete: Bool) {
    interactive = false
    animated = false
    shouldBeInteractive = false
    didFinishedTransition = didComplete
    transitionContext?.finishInteractiveTransition()
    transitionContext?.completeTransition(true)
}

func updateInteractiveTransition(percentComplete: CGFloat) {
    if self.reverse {
        print(percentComplete)
        self.tovc.view.frame.origin.x = (self.fromvc.view.frame.maxX * (percentComplete)) - self.fromvc.view.frame.maxX
    }
}

func finishInteractiveTransition() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations: {
        if self.reverse {
            self.tovc.view.frame.origin.x = self.fromvc.view.frame.origin.x
        }
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.animated = false
            self.reverse = !self.reverse
            self.completeTransition(true)
    })
}

func cancelInteractiveTransition() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations: {
        if self.reverse {
            self.tovc.view.frame.origin.x = -self.fromvc.view.frame.maxX
        }
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.animated = false
            self.completeTransition(true)
    })
}

func transitionWasCancelled() -> Bool {
    return didFinishedTransition
}

func targetTransform() -> CGAffineTransform {
    return CGAffineTransform()
}

func completionSpeed() -> CGFloat {
    return 1 - percentTransition
}

func panned(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch pan.state {
    case .Began:
        animated = true
        shouldBeInteractive = true
        didStartedTransition = true
        didFinishedTransition = false
        sourceViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        updateInteractiveTransition(0)
        break
    case .Changed:
        percentTransition = CGFloat(pan.translationInView(sourceViewController!.view).x / sourceViewController!.view.frame.width)
        if percentTransition < 0.0 {
            percentTransition = 0.0
        } else if percentTransition > 1.0 {
            percentTransition = 1.0
        }
        updateInteractiveTransition(percentTransition)
        break
    case .Ended, .Failed, .Cancelled:
        animated = false
        shouldBeInteractive = false
        didStartedTransition = false
        didFinishedTransition = true
        if percentTransition < 0.8 {
            cancelInteractiveTransition()
        } else {
            finishInteractiveTransition()
        }
        break
    case .Possible:
        break
    }
}
```

}

The `animateTransition` works perfectly and dismiss my fromViewController but during my `InteractiveTransition` when I call `finishInteractiveTransition()` and then `completeTransition(true)`, I still have my both view :

[image]

But on Apple they said :

> You must call this method after your animations have completed to notify the system that the transition animation is done. The parameter you pass must indicate whether the animations completed successfully. For interactive animations, you must call this method in addition to the finishInteractiveTransition or cancelInteractiveTransition method. The best place to call this method is in the completion block of your animations.

So, what am I doing wrong ?

I am using ios9, swift 2, Xcode 7 beta 6

Comment: I notice you are always saying `completeTransition(true)`. That's wrong. You must pass a Bool saying whether or not we were cancelled. You must pass `true` if the transition was completed, `false` if it was cancelled.

Comment: Oh, it was a mistake. I corrected that in `ancelInteractiveTransition()` which now call `self.completeTransition(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

i should call `transitionContext.completeTransition(true)` in function `finishInteractiveTransition()`  but on my previous code `transitionContext` was not the same that in `startInteractiveTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)`

So i add one variable :

```
private var Context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?
```

and use this to call :

```
transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
```

or

```
transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
```